# Page not loaded on refresh using vuex and getter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, getter

Trying to solve page refresh issue that occurs using vuex and getters. I must be missing something on how the reactivity works, but haven't been able to identify what after searching around and reading vue pages on reactivity.

As an example, I have a component that will initially load just fine:

1. Create lifecycle dispatches action to retrieve data from API and push to array in state
2. Computed property in component retrieves data using getter (filter array to specific person)
3. Component displays a few properties in array

When page is refreshed it seems that the action is called again and data retrieved but it doesn't seem like the getter works correctly to get the new data and page does not load. If I test accessing the data in the state directly then refresh works fine. So it seems that the data is properly loaded to the state when refreshing but the getter somehow doesn't have it?

Appreciate any help!

```
Component:
<script>
export default {
  props: ["id"],

  computed: {
    player() {
      return this.$store.getters["player/getPlayerById"](this.id);
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("player/fetchPlayer", this.id);
  }
};
</script>

getter:
getPlayerById: state => id => {
    return state.players.find(plr => plr.PlayerID === id);
  }

action: 
    var promise = EventService.getPlayer(id)
      .then(response => {
        commit("ADD_PLAYER", response.data);
      })
  
ADD_PLAYER mutation:
  ADD_PLAYER(state, player) {
    state.players.push(player[0]);
  }
```

Comment: Okay, maybe this isn't about the getters, reactivity, et... As I have continued playing/testing, if I pass in a specific id to the getter in the computed property instead of the prop this.id it loads fine on refresh.  I don't understand why.  When I log the value to the console of this.id it is the same value as the hard coded value but the result is different.

Comment: Refreshing the browser reinitializes the Vue application.  If you are not on the initial home page of the app when you refresh, you can have strange issues.  Since you talk about passing a prop, if you are refreshing a page that normally you have to navigate to, that is probably causing the error.